# Не удается добавить тень на стыке блоков. Какие есть решения?

Tags: html, css, css3, вёрстка, css-animation

Добавляю тень к хедеру.

Если следующий за ним блок прозрачен - все ок.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если следующий блок имеет цвет - тень ичезает.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощь z-index исправить не удалось. 
Как это можно еще решить?

Короткий пример:

```css
.header{
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px grey;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.block{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="header"></div>
<div class="block"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Всё же видно. Просто фон сливается с тенью..? Попробуйте поменять на красный и увидите, что тень есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тень такого же цвета как и блок.
Можно сделать тень через rgba(), например:

```css
.header{
  height: 40px;
  background-color: red;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px rgba(0,0,0, 0.35);
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.block{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/3.0.2/normalize.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="header"></div>
<div class="block"></div>

</body>
</html>
```